# Why I am getting "none" every time the loop is executed once?

Tags: python-2.7

[I don't know why it is there. If it has something to do with the function diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNzSA.png)

Comment: You `print` the return value of `diff`. Since `diff` does not return anything explicitly, it returns a `None` implictly.

Comment: @Nirbhay: The function was called first from the loop but didn't get anything till `print differ` was executed and at the end, the function didn't return anything so you get `None`.

Comment: this was useful, up and working!! Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `diff` not returning anything that's why `print diff(z)` printing out just `None`. It should be like this

```
def diff(n):
    x = n**(1.0/2)
    y = (n-2)**(1.0/2)
    differ = x-y
    return differ

z = 2
while z >= 0 and z <= 100:
    print diff(z)
    z = z+1
```

Answer (score 0):

as the comment correctly points out, `diff` has no explicit return value. This would not be too bad, as `diff` has the desired side-effect of printing the number you want. However, since you ask python to print the result of `diff` in the while loop, you will get `None` every time `diff` is asked to give a return value. You can fix this by changing diff to not have side-effects but rather return the value (simply change `print` to `return`) or call the function for its side-effect but not try to print its return-value (get rid of the `print` statement in the while loop).

hope this helps